# REISUO vs shutdown now

Tags: shutdown

You can use `shutdown now` command or REISUO trick to shutdown your computer, but what way is preferred over another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `shutdown` will ask the services to shut down nicely one by one, then it u(n)mounts your file systems in a clean manner. Only then it switches off the power.

The `REISUB` or similar shortcuts are for emergencies only, when the normal shutdown procedure does not work. For example, your file systems are not u(n)mounted but instead mounted read-only, hoping that shutting down will not damage file system structures much in this case - not as much as pulling the plug right away. The same goes for userspace programs - e.g. your LibreOffice would just be killed with `REISUB` without being able to save files. Your data might be lost.

Therefore, whenever possible please stick to the standard way of shutting down or rebooting.

Sometimes when I find I cannot shut down the system (e.g. as a user with too few privileges) I log out, then I go to a console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) where I press the power button (briefly!) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. That is (in the standard configuration) still a safe way to shut down / reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't get mad and listen:

Sorry to inform you, but in your case, just from the wording of the question,  it is clear that you using REISUO, is like giving gun with unlocked safety to a child, barrel facing towards the face. Child being you.

Always shut down the computer with commands and/or clicks, unless you actually understand what the system reqest sequence is doing.